# Creating an image with MiniMagick from scratch

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

I am trying to create an image with Minimagick by doing:

```
collage = MiniMagick::Image.create "jpg", false do |c|
    c.size "1024x768"
    c.canvas "white"
end
```

But this is not working. I haven't been able to find anything on the docs. Is this even possible? I currently get this error:

```
/home/hommie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:252:in `size': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Thanks

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get an error or exception? Do you get silence but the variable is nil?

Comment: I have added the error that I am getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MiniMagick Image.create method giving an ArgumentError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495026/minimagick-image-create-method-giving-an-argumenterror)

Answer (score 1):

A very late answer, hopefully useful for future searchers.. you can consider [Tool](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#metal) class and do something like:

```rb
MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |img|
  img.size "100x100"
  img << "canvas:white"
  img << "img.png"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

MiniMagick does not support image creation. The `create` method is just used to create an Image object. From [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/probablycorey/mini_magick/master/MiniMagick/Image#create-class_method):

> Used to create a new Image object data-copy. Not used to “paint” or
>   that kind of thing.
>
> Takes an extension in a block and can be used to build a new Image
>   object. Used by both #open and #read to create a new object! Ensures
>   we have a good tempfile!

If you want to create a new image you will have to use [rmagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick)